# libjpegTurbo: libjpeg-62 File not recognized

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to use libjpeg-turbo with qt.
I downloaded libjpeg-turbo and installed. I wanted to use it within a project but I got the following fault:

> C:\libjpeg-turbo-gcc64\bin\libjpeg-62.dll:-1: Error: file not
>   recognized: File format not recognized

As soon as I removed the libjpeg-62.dll I received the following fault:

> C:\test\main.cpp:8: Error: undefined reference to
>   `tjInitCompress'

Why is the libjpeg-62 not recognizing the file format?

Thanks for help,
Willy

PS. Here is the code:

test.pro

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp


INCLUDEPATH += C:\libjpeg-turbo-gcc64\include
LIBS += -LC:\libjpeg-turbo-gcc64\bin -llibjpeg-62
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <turbojpeg.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    tjhandle _jpegCompressor = tjInitCompress();


    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You should keep `libjpeg-62.dll`, the problem is that it hasn't been recognized yet. What's the operating system and what's the compiler you are using?

Comment: hi, i use win7 64bit, Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)
Now i have download libjpeg-turbo-gcc and deinstalled the 64 Versision. Now it recognized the dll but i still have the Error
`C:\test\main.cpp:8: Error: undefined reference to `tjInitCompress'`

Answer (score 0):

Ok now it works,

it was the wrong version of libjpeg-turbo. Now I use the libjpeg-turbo-gcc and not the libjpeg-turbo-gcc64. Also i change the Libs-Path to 
`LIBS += "C://libjpeg-turbo-gcc64//bin//libjpeg-62.dll"`

MfG Willy